# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am getting the following error in startup.cs:
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions' from assembly: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdn9g.png
and internal server error while running :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjMML.png

Here is my project.json file:

```
  {
  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "4.2.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "build"
    },

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I know that it is a dependency error but i cant figure out where.Also, I am getting dependency conflict issues if i change the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore version from "1.0.0-rc2-final" to "1.0.0".

Comment: update your asp.net core sdk and packages to latest 1.1 version.

Comment: I am almost sure that the reason is that you mixed 1.0.0-rc2-final, 1.1.x and 1.0.x packages. Either stick to 1.0.x or 1.1.x.